# Courier generic subaddressing

Tags: debian, email, courier

I have a Courier MTA that picks up the mail for all the virtual users. Now I would like to implement sub addressing. Unfortunately, the documentation didn't help me that much, because at the points where I needed help it was too vague.

Basically I want that mail that is directed to user-foo@example.com will be put into the user's foo/ directory. In that case **foo** should be generic, so no matter what will appear after the dash, it should automatically create the folder and put the mail in it.

So, does anyone have expierence with it?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was easier than I had hoped

```
    touch ~/.courier-default
```

https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/misc/courier-email-subaddressing/